# mov.w vs movw in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, mov

Going through the [Rust Embedded discovery book](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/07-registers/type-safe-manipulation.html), I frequently see ARM assembly code that looks like this:

```
 08000248 <registers::__cortex_m_rt_main::h199f1359501d5c71>:
 8000248:       push    {r7, lr}
 800024a:       mov r7, sp
 800024c:       bl  #0x22
 8000250:       movw    r0, #0x1018
 8000254:       mov.w   r1, #0x200
 8000258:       movt    r0, #0x4800
 800025c:       str r1, [r0]
 800025e:       mov.w   r1, #0x800
 8000262:       str r1, [r0]
 8000264:       mov.w   r1, #0x2000000
 8000268:       str r1, [r0]
 800026a:       mov.w   r1, #0x8000000
 800026e:       str r1, [r0]
 8000270:       b   #-0x4 <registers::__cortex_m_rt_main::h199f1359501d5c71+0x28>
```

I did some reading on ARM assembly, and I understand that `mov` can either take a 32bit operand or a 16bit immediate value (for a 32bit system). The `movt`/`movw` instructions let me specify the high/low bytes of my 32bit register, but I couldn't find any reference on `mov.w`. What is the difference between `movw` and `mov.w`?

Comment: `mov.w` is just a `mov` instruction.  The disassembler appends a `.w` suffix to indicate that a 32 bit encoding of the instruction was used.

Comment: `movw` **cannot** encode a 32-bit immediate value, because ARM instructions are at most 4 bytes long, so the pidgeonhole principle says no to what you "understand".

Comment: If you want to be sure, output the opcodes with the disassembly and verify the codes for `movw` and `mov.w` are the same.  The thing I see is that `mov.w` is being used for address construction above while the other is only being used for 32-bit number construction.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I thought assembly didn't care about this? Addresses should be treated just like any other 32-bit number, no?

Comment: It is true that the move instructions don't know or care whether the value being moved is an address or something else. But the compiler might find one kind of move **more suitable** for loading addresses. In the specific case you provided, `movw` and `movt` are used to load a memory address into a register while `mov.w` loads the value that will ultimately be stored at that address.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction width specifiers `.W` and `.N` control the size of T32 instruction encodings.

Visit [Instruction width specifiers](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100076/0200/a32-t32-instruction-set-reference/a32-and-t32-instructions/instruction-width-specifiers)